# Non-tonal (and tonal) languages and inflection

Tags: inflection, tone, tonal-languages

I want to know whethere there are any standards that would allow a non-tonal (or tonal) spoken language like English to be augmented with diacritics to denote how the tone varies, as the entire sentence is pronounced, or in particular places.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The standard used for English by phoneticians these days is [TOBI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ToBI). It is language-specific enough that if you want to apply it to French, you'd have to use TODI, TOBI etc. as models for developing FTOBI, since it requires language-specific categorization decisions. It doesn't actually use tone mark diacritics like acute, circumflex etc. as are conventional in phonological tone systems, instead it used letters H, L, %, +, -, *, !.